# fadeIn in when in view, fadeOut when only bottom is visible

Tags: jquery-waypoints

Iam using the waypoints plugin, but am open for others.
so far i have managed to get the div to fadeIn when iam scrolling down and its rached 30%:

```
element.waypoint(function(){            
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);          
},{
    offset: '30%'
});
```

But iam not able to make it fadeout again, when its getting out of view again.

Thanks for the help.

is this a too hard question for mighty stackoverflow? ...

Answer (score 0):

You can do different things depending on the direction you are scrolling when you cross that waypoint trigger spot using the `direction` parameter that is passed to the function:

```
element.waypont(function(direction) {
  if (direction === 'down') { ... }
  else { ... }
}, { offset: '30%' });
```

You can also create multiple waypoints with different offsets, so you can react to the element hitting different parts of the page:

```
element
  .waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible');
  }, { offset: '10%' })
  .waypoint(function(direction) {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible');
  }, { offset: '90%' });
```